# how to set border radius for UIImage in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I would like to have a UIImage with a border radius at 21% to make it an image look similar to an app icon. I am using the following code below:

```
cell.imageView?.image = image
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 21
//cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The problem with this is that it makes the image round, which is not what I want. I simply want it to look square, as if the icon was for an app image, basically an HTML equivalent of `border-radius: 21%;`

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `cornerRadius` to `21` sets it to 21 points, not 21 percent of the image's size.

You need to calculate 21% of the image's size.

```
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = image.size.width * 0.21
```

This assumes you want 21% of the image's width.

Comment: Thank you. I was also working on this answer. I haven't seen this asked since I joined SO last year so it easily deserves my up vote.